# Unable to get Updated textarea Value

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, textarea

I have a problem:

I have a textarea on my page that looks like this:

```
<textarea id='redactor_content' name='redactor_content' style='width: 720px; height: 320px;'>$news[3]</textarea>
```

Where `$news[3]` is a php variable that I get from MySQL. `redactor_content` is a WYSIWYG editor where I edit the content of `$news[3]`. After the content is edited, I want to pass it to mysql to update the table with the following JavaScript:

```
function update_news(n_id) {
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var news_body = $('#redactor_content').val();
    alert(news_body);
    $.post(
        "update.php",
        {n_id: n_id, title: title, body: news_body},
        "html"
    )};
```

There are 2 more variables in JS which are `n_id` and `title`. Both are working OK. But when the alert pops up with the news_body variable I see the old version of textarea (which was initially in the $news[3] variable), not the new, updated one.

I'm stuck guys. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of the wysiwyg editors create a new separate section on the page (an iframe usually) that overlays the textarea they're replacing. You'd need to tell the editor to copy the data in the "fancy" graphical version back to the original form fields so your JS can get the updated version. or figure out how/where the editor is storing the overlayed version so you can grab it from there.

Comment: thanks, will try looking this way. btw, if that helps, the editor I'm using is ElRTE

Comment: Thanks for the help, the answer to my question is :

need to replace this line :

    var news_body = $('#redactor_content').val();


with this line :
 
    var news_body = $('#redactor_content').elrte('val');


As Marc B told, there's a some sort of overlay made by the ElTRE editor.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some client side functionality that the `redactor_content` exposes to allow you to retrieve the value correctly. Something like `$('#redactor_content')[0].getTextValue()` or something.

That isn't the actual code mind you, just an example of how it possible works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, the answer to my question is :

need to replace this line :

```
var news_body = $('#redactor_content').val();
```

with this line :

```
var news_body = $('#redactor_content').elrte('val');
```