# javascript textarea value not updating

Tags: javascript

A very bizarre problem using sharepoint 2007.  I don't know if SP is the issue but here goes.  We are doing a form validation during an onSubmit, the valdidateForm() function is called, it loads all the form field values for testing and its showing us a particular textareas pre-edits value...not the post-edits value.  No matter what we change in the textarea, the test alerts only shows us what was in the textarea when the form loaded.

I came across this thread and think our problem is the same: [Unable to get Updated textarea Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070414/unable-to-get-updated-textarea-value)

In the code we find this:

```
<textarea id="ctl00_m_g_2fb9e824_5f6c_4d91_afdb_5420a2ae2443_ctl00_ctl04_ctl22_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" class="ms-long" dir="none" title="Root Cause Determination" cols="20" rows="6" name="ctl00$m$g_2fb9e824_5f6c_4d91_afdb_5420a2ae2443$ctl00$ctl04$ctl22$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField"><div>Momentary network hiccup. New Text. Even Newer Text. </div></textarea>

<input id="ctl00_m_g_2fb9e824_5f6c_4d91_afdb_5420a2ae2443_ctl00_ctl04_ctl22_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave" type="HIDDEN" name="ctl00$m$g_2fb9e824_5f6c_4d91_afdb_5420a2ae2443$ctl00$ctl04$ctl22$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField_spSave">
```

and our code is grabbing and alerting the textarea value that is not reflecting the edits...when we grab the HIDDEN matching  and try to alert display that field nothing comes up.  Its empty.

We are baffled and can't find any other related textarea or referring editor fields.

Comment: ...and there are no frames or iframes embedded in the page that would be coming from an overlay editor (as per the info in the posted thread)

Comment: It is clear from id that it is generate from server side control. Please check if your text-area is updated by button out-side update-panel or vice-versa. UpdatePanel sometimes troubles like what you are facing.

Comment: Are you really sure that you have only UNIQUE id? Check that adding  `document.getElementById("id").length`in the console.log at the end of the last script loaded

Comment: are you using `.innerText`? Can you post the validation code that doesn't work?